# Why does this XSS challenge require %0A to work?

Tags: xss

I came across [this hack.me XSS challenge](https://hack.me/103185/link-shortening-website-xss.html).

Solution to this challenge is:

```
javascript://%0Aalert(1)
```

I'm confused with `%0A`. Why does it not work with this payload?

```
javascript://alert(1)
```

Answer (score 6):

**It's required to terminate a Javascript comment.**

The challenge enforces a link format along the lines of `[a-z]*://.*`. Here, the idea is to inject JS via the `javascript:` pseudo protocol. So, in order to adhere to the link format, you have to start your sequence with `javascript://`.

But since everything behind the colon is interpreted as JS, you run into a problem: `//` introduces a single-line comment in JS, so everything that comes after it will be commented out until a newline character appears. This will do nothing:

```
//alert(1)
```

`%0a` is the URL-encoded version of an ASCII newline, so your payload effectively becomes this:

```
//
alert(1)
```